# Mailto link with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, mailto

I have a mailto link on my site that is working fine. However, I want to perform a .click() event on it to log when the user clicks that link. I have the .click event working and performing the ajax request, but now the mailto link doesn't open the email client. Is it possible to run a jquery function before the client opens, but still make the client open?

here is the code I have (it just opens a blank window in the browser)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                    jQuery('span.email a').on('click',function (){
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '', //url here
                            data: {comment: 'Email Sent', category : 'EE', store_id: '" . $this->store_id . "'},
                            success: function (data){jQuery('#alerts').html(data);}
                        });
                    window.location.href= $(this).prop('href');
                });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `window.location.href= $(this).prop('href');`. If you just let the click continue on as normal, it should do what you want.

Comment: When I do that, the ajax request happens fine, but the client doesn't open. However, when I remove the onclick event, the client opens.

Comment: Try passing `asyc: true` with the ajaxed object.

Comment: Nevermind, I just downgraded from Outlook 2010 to 2003 and now the mailto link doesn't work at all. I had a friend try it and its working fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: My pleasure. If you found this answered your question, please do mark it as Answered :)

Answer (score 5):

In order for this to work you will need to set the async to false.

See http://jsfiddle.net/5nwu7/3/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery('span.email a').on('click',function (){
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '', //url here
                        data: {comment: 'Email Sent', category : 'EE', store_id: '" . $this->store_id . "'},
                        success: function (data){jQuery('#alerts').html(data);},
                        async: false
                    });
                //You don't need this ---window.location.href= $(this).prop('href');
            });
            </script>
```

This is because some browsers will cancel your current ajax request when opening the mail client.  You can test this by going to that jsfiddle I posted and removing the async line (tested in chrome 23.0.1271.97 m, windows 7, outlook 2007.)