# telephone protocol with ajax

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm looking to increment (in a database) the number of times a phone number is tapped in a mobile browser. I'm using the `tel://` protocol on an anchor, as in:

`<a class='phone-number' href='tel:12345678901'>Call Now!</a>`

The idea is to send an AJAX request to the server when the link is tapped.

```
$(".phone-number").click(function(e){
    var url = "phone_tap.php";
    var data = {id: 1};
    $.post(url, data, function(r){
        if(r.success){}
    });
}
```

However, in both web and mobile browsers, the AJAX request seems to get cancelled by the browser, as it invokes it's native program.

Has anybody experienced this before? Solutions?

Found exact same question [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-tel-links) with no answers.

Comment: I wonder if you invoke the call on `touchstart` if it will trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers - however, I found the solution by hunting down [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164966/mailto-link-with-jquery) involving the `mailto://` protocol instead of the `tel://` protocol.

The solution is to use jQuery `$.ajax`'s `async: false` property:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    method: "POST"
}).then(function(r){
    if(r.success){}
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Please note possible repercussions?

Comment: It's AsynchronousJAX. With `async:false` you're making it synchronous. So no error at all but at least a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works.

Change the link to:

```
<a class="phone-number" href="#" data-number="123456789">Call ya!</a>
```

And the click handler to:

```
$(".phone-number").on("click", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var url = "phone_tap.php";
    var data = {id: 1};
    $.post(url, data, function(r){
        if(r.success){
            window.location = "tel://" + $(this).data("number");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the number in the href in your html, you could redirect the resoponse to it *after incrementing the counter* on the server.

You could remove the ajax call in its entirety and just link to `phone_tap.php?id=...` for each number.

Inside `phone_tap.php` you'd have to do something like:

```
UPDATE statistics SET number_of_taps=number_of_taps+1 WHERE id=:id
```

and end with something like:

```
header('location: tel:' . $phone_number);
```

That would seem to be the simplest wat to do it to me, and as a bonus it would also likely prevent scrapers from getting the phone numbers from your pages. (just denying access in robots.txt won't really stop anyone)